# How to subtract from a number with a variable amount of other numbers?

Tags: vb.net

Sorry for the edits, im tired and im a moron, so heres my problem=
Lets say this is my code :

```
Dim ogquantity,subtractedquantity as double
Private Sub CalculateMe
ogquantity = numericupdown1.value
subtractedquantity = ogquantity - numericupdown2.value
subtractedquantity = ogquantity - numericupdown3.value
subtractedquantity = ogquantity - numericupdown4.value
subtractedquantity = ogquantity - numericupdown5.value
label1.text = subtractedquantity
End Sub
```

And i set "CalculateMe" as code for 1-5 numericupdowns_valuechanged
This wont output a changed value..
And the reason i have it set up like this is because in the actual code numericupdown might change subtractedquantity1 or subtractedquantity28, it is decided with a dropdown menu for each numericupdown.
something like this:

```
Dim item1stock, item1originalstock As Double
        If itemselector1name.Text = itemdefiner1name.text Then
            item1stock = item1originalstock - itemselector1quantity.value
            itemselector1label.text = item1stock
        End If
        If itemselector2name.Text = itemdefiner1name.text Then
            item1stock = item1originalstock - itemselector2quantity.value
            itemselector2label.text = item1stock
        End If
```

and i would repeat check for every item like this but if two different 'itemselectorquantity' is supposed to subtract from the same original stock quantity that i dont know how to set up.. Im trying my best here but im new to coding and bad at explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Create one event handler for all NUDs: `Private Sub NumbersChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged, NumericUpDown2.ValueChanged, ..., NumericUpDownN.ValueChanged`, then you can simply call a `DoCalculations()` method inside that event handler.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Please [edit] the question and include your code, preferably with a screenshot of your form. See [repro] for guidance on what parts of the code you should include.

Comment: Being completely honest here.  Sounds to me like you really aren't sure of the logic here.  A better approach for now is forget about the coding for now, grab a pen and paper and work out the logic first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather muddled but, as an example of the sort of thing you might do if you want to use zero, one or more of a set of controls based on another set of controls, consider this example that uses `CheckBoxes` to specify which `NumericUpDowns` to subtract from an initial quantity:

```vb
Private Function SubtractCheckedValues(value As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim checkBoxes = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4}
    Dim numericUpDowns = {NumericUpDown1, NumericUpDown2, NumericUpDown3, NumericUpDown4}

    For i = 0 To checkBoxes.GetUpperBound(0)
        If checkBoxes(i).Checked Then
            value -= numericUpDowns(i).Value
        End If
    Next

    Return value
End Function
```